# Composite Keys or Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the best way to associate/join my tables 'teams' and 'schedules'. My models are:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :conf, :div, :key, :name
  self.primary_key = "key" #Abbreviations for strings 'CHI', 'TB', 'SEA' etc.

  has_many :schedules, foreign_key: [:away_team, :home_team]
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_team, :date, :home_team, :season, :week, :team_key
  self.primary_keys = :away_team, :home_team #Abbreviations for strings 'CHI', 'TB', 'SEA' etc.

  belongs_to :team, primary_key: "key"
end
```

I installed the gem "composite_primary_keys", "~> 5.0.13".

In rails console when I assign a variable

```
>> team = Team.find("SEA")

SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."key" = ? LIMIT 1  [["key", "SEA"]]
=> #<Team key: "SEA", city: "Seattle", name: "Seahawks", conf: "NFC", div: "West">
```

it displays Seattle perfectly, but when I run:

```
>> team.schedules

SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE ("schedules"."away_team" = 'SEA' AND "schedules"."home_team" IS NULL) 
=> []
```

The 'schedule' table has data for 'SEA' in the home_team column.

Would a join table be a better solution? If so, how would you do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't use composit keys, if you don't have to (and you don't in this case).
Primary keys are for accessing individual items, not for constraints or business logic.
In your case, the primary index can't be used to select schedules by home_team.

Also it's a good idea to use Rails conventions as much as possible. It makes life easier.
Use `id` as primary key and for joining tables.

I see that your schedule belongs to **two** teams, and team have two kinds of schedules (home and away). So you models could look like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :conf, :div, :key, :name

  has_many :home_schedules, class_name: 'Schedule', foreign_key: :home_team_id
  has_many :away_schedules, class_name: 'Schedule', foreign_key: :away_team_id

  def schedules
    home_schedules + away_schedules
  end
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_team, :date, :home_team, :season, :week, :team_key

  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

then

```
team = Team.find_by_key('SEA')
team.schedules
```

**Added**

I would generate the model with

```
rails g model Team city conf div short_cut name
rails g model Schedule day:date season week:integer home_team_id:integer away_team_id:integer
```

You link teams to fans by adding `team_id` to `Fan`. You can always use the team's short_cut (as I named your former key attribute) to display or select the team, but let Rails use `id` for all the internal stuff.

Comment: `home_schedules` and `away_schedules` are arrays, `+` is merging arrays

Comment: Thank you Martin, I really appreciate your help! Here's what I'm getting now. '>> team = Team.find_by_key('SEA')
ArgumentError: Unknown key: class'

Comment: I can see, using `key` as an attribute name is not a good idea. I also would avoid `date` as an attribute name.

Comment: :key:string was set as the primary_key instead of id:integer in the teams table. The teams table also includes 'has_many :fans, foreign_key: "team_key"' for the fans table. This way I can join the teams table to the fans based on the team the fans select. '>> team.fans' works great. The 'date' column in the 'schedule' table is used to determine when the away_team and home_team play. How would you recommend setting it up?

Comment: DB schema
`create_table "schedules", :id => false, :force => true do |t|    
t.integer  "season"  
t.integer  "week"  
t.datetime "date"  
t.string   "away_team"    
t.string   "home_team"  
t.string   "team_key"  
end  
  
create_table "teams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|    
t.string "key"  
t.string "city"  
t.string "name"  
t.string "conf"  
t.string "div"  
end`

Comment: `create_table "fans", :force => true do |t|  
    t.string   "name"  
    t.string   "email"  
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false  
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false  
    t.string   "team_key"  
  end  

  add_index "fans", ["team_key"], :name => "index_fans_on_team_key"`

Comment: `create_table "teams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|  
t.string "key"  
t.string "city"  
t.string "name"  
t.string "conf"  
t.string "div"  
end`

Comment: Hi Martin, Well I did what you suggested and recreated the tables (teams, schedules) with the primary key of 'id'. One issue I had was the 'has_many' and 'belongs_to' didn't work with the name 'class:'. I changed it to 'class_name' and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Answer accepted ;-)! Btw: Don't forget to change the 'class:' to 'class_name:' in the 'Schedule' model. Thank again! I'm sure I'll be posting some more questions in the future.